# Should I extract this code out into methods?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to get some values and then pass that to an object property.

Should I refactor this out into a few methods?  If so, should I refactor it out for each call.  A Type, A property etc.

```
//base item
var item = aItem;

//The type of the item
var type = item.GetType();

//The property -- In this example a list of strings -- can be list<int> etc.
var property = type.GetProperty("Strings");

//The type of the property
var propertyType = property.PropertyType;

//Value to be converted value is a object
var value = property.GetValue(item);

//New value changing type -- Was showing a list of list -- Was using this when i had a List<object>
//var newValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType);

//The object property
ListData = value;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this question be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @BrunoToffolo Nope.  This is considered "example code", which is off-topic over on Code Review.

Comment: @BrunoToffolo maybe if OP brought their real code. This is likely to get closed as example code on Code Review.

Comment: And likely closed as "opinion based" on SO :) There is really no code that does not deserve some refactoring...

Answer (score 3):

Methods should only contain code that executes **one** Task. In your code that is given. It returns the content of a list from an object via reflection.

In my opinion you should leave it at that. But create a method to do this:

```
object GetListData(object item){
    //your code
    return value; 
}
```